# R Markdown / Quarto - Avoid loading package every time I knit a document

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, quarto

Simple question but can't find a solution.
I have a quarto document (but this apply to Markdown as well) in which I use R to execute some code. Obviously, in the first chunk of the document, I load the packages needed (let's say for example):

````
```{r setup}
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
```
````

Now, everytime I knit the file to render the document, these packages are loaded, which can be pretty time consuming especially if you have a long list of packages to import. using `cache=TRUE` doesn't seem to work properly. Is there anyway to avoid loading the package everytime I knit the document, and only load them when they are not loaded in the environment/in the first knit call of the session at least?

Comment: You could try not to load packages, but accessing functions using double colon, i.e. `survival::coxph`.

Comment: @jay.sf this is a nice suggestion - thanks - however somewhat impractical if someone have a long document and a long list of functions to be called?

Comment: It can be a good practice to move expensive calculations outside the Markdown / Quarto document into a .R script that saves its results to disk.  Then, the Markdown / Quarto can load those results.  The benefit is that you often want to tweak the appearance of tables and figures without running all the calculations all over again.  I realize this doesn't answer your question, but am posting in case it's useful.

Comment: @jay.sf:  Using the double colon notation does cause the package to load, it just doesn't put it on the search list.  Usually it's the loading that is slow, so that probably won't help.  (Though it might help if the production of the object is cached.)

Comment: @user2554330 I thought it loads the namespace, but doesn't attach it. Won't that be faster?

Comment: @jay.sf:  It should be faster, but I wouldn't expect a big difference.  Most of the work happens during loading.

Comment: @userq8957289475 Notice, that one of your packages loads 29 dependencies, maybe you could do without it.

Comment: (1) Reduce your library footprint, many/most users don't actually use all packages within `library(tidyverse)`. If you need dplyr/tidyr/stringr, then load them explicitly and none others. (2) Add them only in the code blocks that need them, and turn on caching for those code blocks; that way, if a code block has a cache _hit_, then it should not need to load the package. (3) Be wary of "premature optimization": if it would be a change from (say) 10 seconds to 7, then is it worth the effort to reduce? What's the current runtime? How much work are you willing to do to "convert" to base R?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to run Quarto or RMarkdown is in a clean session, not in the current session.  So you normally only have a minimal set of packages already loaded.

If you run `rmarkdown::render( ... )` in a session, that doesn't happen, and things will run in the current session.  That will speed up `library()` calls a lot, because they do nothing if the package has already been attached to the search list.

I don't know if something similar is available for Quarto, but in any case, it's a risky strategy:  what you hope for from an RMarkdown or Quarto document is something that is reproducible. If you run in the current session, you run the risk of getting results that depend on variables in the current session.

I'd advise you to identify which packages are slow to load, and try to follow @Arthur's suggestion from a comment:  precompute the objects that those packages produce, and just load them in the document.  Then you may not need the package at all.

Comment: It would be great if knitting saved the state of libraries for the knitted file and session. Then if you knit the same file again in the same session, it could check the previously knitted libraries against the code to see whether there is any reason to load libraries again.

Comment: The only reason to load packages is if they have not been loaded yet.  That will always be true if you're running in a clean session, as you should be.  If you are rendering multiple times in the same session the only reason you would need to load the package again is if you explicitly unloaded it.  So don't do that.